# Why does Safari obscure javascript document.write outputs while prompt is active?

Tags: javascript, safari, document.write

I have noticed a discrepancy in how Safari handles the document.write output versus how Firefox and Chrome do, and wanted to ask for feedback, please.

I am learning HTML & javascript and today I wrote a very simple script to enable a user to guess a number between 1-10 to see if it matched the one the program was "thinking of." After each incorrect guess, I use document.write to display a message/feedback to the page. I have observed that in Firefox and Chrome this feedback is displayed as intended, but in Safari (v9.0.3 on El Capitan) it is obscured until the prompt window is not active (or after the while loop completes, I can't tell which).

I have done some searching on here and some googling but can't find why this is occurring. Is this a known issue with Safari and I'd just need to take a different approach to providing text feedback to the page?

This is my first time posting a question, so pardon any noob formatting or whatnot! I've pasted my code below. Thank you very much!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Guess The Number</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = Math.random();
    x = Math.round(x * 10);
    var y = "";
    while (y != "X" && y != x)
        {
        y = prompt("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10. Guess the number! Or enter X to give up.");

        if (y == "X")
            {
            document.write("Aw, sorry you gave up!<br/>");
            } else if (y == x)
                {
                document.write("That's right! Good guess!<br/>");
                } else
                    {
                    document.write("Nope! Try again!<br/>");
                    }
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you are talking about start learning, so a little advice, do not use both Safari or IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with script execution in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453328/problem-with-script-execution-in-safari)